# xampp does not run php, browser asks what to do with file

Tags: php, xampp

I just installed xampp from www.apachefriends.org.
Per the instructions I ran
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
Then xampp started and I saw the gui control panel. Everything great so far.
I verified it works by going to localhost in Firefox. I saw the welcome screen.

Then,I navigate to my test html. It is a contact which runs a php file when clicking submit.

Then firefox sends a message what to do with my php script, sendeail (save or select an application). sendeail is a no-brainer php script for email which I found on the internet years ago. It works when running from my server and has been for ages. Just now running locally with xampp started, Firefox doesn't know what to do with it.

[What should Firefox do with this file?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmzU.png)

Do I have to configure xampp somehow?

I couldn't test in Opera or Chrom(ium), the submit form doesn't appear for some reason on my local computer, but whose browsers work fine when accessing the page on the server.

I am running in Linux Ubuntu 16.4 LTS, Firefox 65.0.1 64-bit

--- edit ---

Specifically, the question is that the web browswer sees the .php file and tries to open it, what must I do for the web browser to be passed the code within the .php file, instead?

Comment: Have you php installed on your local Xampp server ?

Comment: If you're running php7 and your scripts are php5 or PHP 3 or lesser, you'll definitely face problems.

Comment: Also make sure you start the Apache in the control panel.... Please let your questions be clear and let us know the difference between the errors messages and your questions by using italic or bold or quotes. I found it difficult to figure out what you were trying to me.... It's still possible I've misunderstood you

Comment: Soheyl, No, I have not installed anything besides Xampp.
Kwaku amoh, I don't know which php I am running.
... and yes, according to the control panel Apache Web server is running

Comment: .apachefriends.org has no explanation of this. I found another page which explains, https://www.fayazmiraz.com/how-to-run-your-first-php-code/.

One has to put their php code into /etc/xampp/htdocs

That's so counter-intuitive!!! OMG why can't I keep my files in my development directory. Yeah, I can test this way, but I'll have to keep updating that directory whenever I have a program change! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

.apachefriends.org has no explanation of this. I found another page which explains, https://www.fayazmiraz.com/how-to-run-your-first-php-code/.

One has to put their php code into /etc/xampp/htdocs

That's so counter-intuitive!!! OMG why can't I keep my files in my development directory. Yeah, I can test this way, but I'll have to keep updating that directory whenever I have a program change! Thank you